# how to return to filled out form from other view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not very experienced in programming, so I apologize in advance if this is a very obvious question.

I have a form in which the user types in his information. It is validated in the `HttpPost` then sent to another page where the contact information are shown so the user can check, if everything is in order. 
if not there is a button for going back to the previous form to correct this.

**Problem:** Everything works perfect, except the going back for correction.

How can I go back to the filled out form?

Below is my code so far:

**Index-Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult DefaultForm(QuestionViewModel viewModel)
    {        
        //method i wrote for populating the dropdown
        dropdownPopulate(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);         
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DefaultForm(QuestionViewModel viewModel, string tbButton)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (tbButton.Equals("questsend"))
                {           
                    return View("Verify", viewModel);
                }
                else if (tbButton.Equals("questupload"))
                {
                    return View(viewModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    dropdownPopulate(viewModel);
                    return View("DefaultForm", viewModel);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                dropdownPopulate(viewModel);
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dropdownPopulate(viewModel);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

**Verify-Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Verify(QuestionViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Verify(QuestionViewModel viewModel, string tbButton)
    {
        #region button verarbeitung

        if (tbButton.Equals("questkorr"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DefaultForm", viewModel);
            }
            else if (tbButton.Equals("questsend"))
            {

                return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherPage");
            }

        #endregion

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Those are the start and end in the view:
**Defaultform**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DefaultForm", "QuestionForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "questionform" }))
        {
<button class="btn btn-default btnusz" type="submit" name="tbButton" value="questsend">Senden</button>
```

**Verify:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Verify", "QuestionForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "verifyform" }))
        {
<button class="btn btn-default btnusz" type="submit" name="tbButton" value="questkorr">Korrigieren</button>
<button class="btn btn-default btnusz" type="submit" name="tbButton" value="questsend">Senden</button>
```

If i need to add more code or information to the question, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You could place an extra method in your controller where you create an instance of your model and populate it with the information, then use that model to show the details, if you need to correct them, simply call the "New" page and pass that model. If you don't need to correct anything, use the model to persist the data.

Or an easier way, you could try with javascript:

```
<a href="##" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;">Go back</a>
```

Comment: The problem with the history.go(-1) is that: if user doesnt fill out one of the inputs then the validation kicks in. So he fills out this input and continues to the Verify-page. then back to correct. and this input he forgot before is highlighted again. filled out but also highlighted.

Comment: @Shaorandra but if there is input that he forgot, he should not be able to continue to the next page? And if the input is filled out, the validation message should dissapear

Comment: He will not be able to continue until he filled out this input. But when returning to the form, the change in the css made by the validation is still active (1 setp back in the history). Can I have on-change-validation based on server-side requirements ([Reqired]...)?